# Horrible experience on Stack powered sites today. What's wrong with this picture?

Tags: discussion, support, user-interface, user-experience, user-information

So, I went over to SuperUser.com to ask this question:

https://superuser.com/questions/199160/any-sites-out-there-that-show-pricing-for-products-that-have-secret-pricing-clo

A little while goes by and I come back to see if there's any answers. It got migrated to webapps.stackexchange.com. Then it was immediately CLOSED by a different user on webapps.stackexchange.com for not being the right kind of question.

*What's wrong with this picture?*

**Web app site = application = software.** There are tons of questions on SuperUser like "Is there a software to manage a home phone?". My question was basically "Is there a web site/app to do X?". I thought this fit into SuperUser, but even if it didn't don't migrate it to a site where it doesn't fit. Right?

The last kick in the face was when I came over here to meta.stackoverflow.com to ask this question and I go to sign in with my normal openid login and just clicking OK, OK, OK didn't associate my normal stackoverflow.com user name (wizlb) with this site. Now I'm user152305 on meta.stackoverflow.com

This was an absolutely horrible experience to me and it made me question the use of any other Stack site ever outside of StackOverflow which I use semi-regularly. Seriously, all this intra-site crap is really annoying. Just make one darned site, will you please?

Comment: I've reopened the question on Web Apps. I'm not convinced of it's value, but I should have waited until there were indications that others held the same view (flags and/or other votes to close) before acting.

Comment: Well one answer was posted so far, so intrinsically it does have value. Obviously, someone "got" my question.

Comment: The OpenID failure may have to do with the fact that SE is currently in the process of moving from its old data center to its new one. MSO can't connect to any of the other sites/global features right now. Sheer bad luck with timing on your part.

Comment: There's some arrogant clap trap going on in this thread. You've got to be daft to think there wouldn't be benefit in a site like the OP is suggesting and further benefit to people in pointing it out if it allready exists. Additionally, to say that Enterprise App isn't an understood term is silly.

Comment: Arrogant clap trap indeed. Give people a little power and they definitely abuse it.

Comment: Personally, I'm not impressed with @user152305's post, it is a very rude one...some of the experiences could not have been helped to some degree (such as MSO being migrated to a different datacenter), and I believe that user152305 could be a lot more understanding...If I had more time, and editing privileges, I would edit this post to be less judgmental and more understanding...IMHO...

Comment: @studiohack could you be more specific about how I was rude in the post? Who was I rude to?

Comment: It could be much worse.  I asked a domain-management question on serverfault, since that is part of my server admin duties.  It was closed.  So then I ask it on superuser, it immediately gets a helpful answer and I mark it "answered".  Come back a few hours later and it's been downvoted (twice!), the useful answer deleted, and migrated to some **other** site that just opened that very day!! (where the same question was upvoted).  Frankly, distinguishing between desk-top apps and web-apps, in such a harsh manner seems very unhelpful.

Comment: @user152305: the language in general, and some of the things you are insinuating...words/phrases like "absolutely horrible", "crap", and "kick in the face"...You have a point, I agree with you there...I'm starting to see this post becoming a place where other annoyed/frustrated users are coming out of the woodwork, so this post may end up being a valuable place for feedback... :-)

Comment: Yeah, I tend to get colorful when I'm in complaint mode. It wasn't really directed at anyone in particular. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Why not post this on the _Super User_ meta? Also, if you had a bad experience here, don't *rant*, just switch to the always helpful (NOT) Yahoo Answers or Experts Exchange. If you don't like that, please read the FAQ. It's there for a reason.

Answer (score 14):

Asking about websites is off-topic for Super User.
Asking about help with your shopping is also off-topic.

Both of these are mentioned in the [Super User FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)

If you're looking to ask about a web application, head on over to **[Unsticking Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)**.

Don't forget that there's always the hard water realisation that not all questions belong to any one of the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: web site <> web application. It shouldn't have been moved to web apps in the first place.

Comment: The OP seems to have phrased it all as a web app, which may explain the salad tossing. @ale

Answer (score 13):

I was amongst the first ones to vote to close the question, let's take it one sentence at a time.

> It's so annoying to be shopping around for an **enterprise level software product** where half the manufacturers don't want to give you pricing unless you call them or let their sales guy take you out to lunch.

OK, enterprise level. Gotcha. What's enterprise level now ?

I'm gonna ask the Big G

[image: enterprise-level]

So I have no proper definition. I'm going to use my understanding of "enterprise level" - Huge monolithic applications ? OK. What sort of products ? No clue.

Moving on:

> I'm looking for some kind of **web resource that lists pricing experiences** for these kinds of products

Ah, you want some web sites/web applications which list these.

Now the Super User FAQ mentions:

[image]

I voted it to move to [WebApps.StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Plain and simple.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_software

Comment: @freiheit: Did you read the "Definition" section of that article? It's very nearly a semantic null and offers damn near nothing beyond a vague idea that *it's businessy*. Not that I think there is no way to form a definition, but it's not going to be easy. Security, reasonable high availability, disaster tolerant data persistence (and have fun making that work with the data non-retention part of "security"), organization wide integration, etc...

Comment: @dmckee: oh, I totally see how you reached the conclusion you did, yes.  However, as a *sysadmin*, I totally knew what he meant by "enterprise level software" immediately, including the amazingly stupid pricing games some of them play... Maybe you just picked the wrong site to move it to.  :)

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=define:+enterprise+software

Comment: I'd actually bold "web resource" instead of the whole phrase.

Answer (score 12):

The root of the problem is that your question was super vague.

> I'm looking for some kind of web resource that lists pricing experiences for these kinds of products.

**Where 'these' are "enterprise level software products."*

Unfortunately, I don't think this question has a good place on any of the sites.

Your question is asking about a website that provides information about actual software products. (whatever they may be)  So, I can see how it's a gray area where the question should go.

Also, meta is a bit broken right now; under normal circumstances you wont be 'kicked in the face' by having to re-register.

Comment: It wasn't vague, I was asking for something very, very specific. I was looking for a web site that let people discuss pricing for the kinds of products that sometimes have hidden prices. "Enterprise level" is a well known term for this level of products.

Comment: Furthermore, who cares if you or anyone else thinks it's vague? I just wanted to ask a question and someone came along and said "your question isn't good enough." It only took two people to vote me off the island.

Comment: @user152305: I'm sorry, but that's not specific at all. "Enterprise level" is a vague buzzword that has at least 2,458,713 different definitions. One of the reasons why the Stack Exchange sites are a good place to get answers is because we allow only **specific questions that are answerable**.

Comment: Instead, they should leave the question open so someone who _does_ understand the question as it was meant... can answer it! That would be amazing!

Comment: It's not vague to a lot of people though. Honestly, I could find 1,00,000 people at least that know that term. At the least...

Comment: @user152305: You know what else would be amazing? **Asking specific, well-written questions.**

Comment: @user152305: I just got done saying that "Enterprise level" has at least 2,458,713 different definitions. Sure, lots of people know what "Enterprise level" is, but I almost guarantee if you ask them what it means they'll all give different answers.

Comment: Seriously, do you think it would have made a difference if I hadn't used the words "Enterprise Level"? Let's see... I'll go post it again and then I'll let you know.

Comment: @user, we appreciate your feedback btw.  But you never said the word 'discuss' in your question. - "I'm looking for some kind of web resource that lists pricing experiences for these kinds of products."

Comment: OK, new question. Let's see how long before it's moved - http://superuser.com/questions/199217/any-web-site-applications-that-let-users-discuss-pricing-for-products-that-have-s

Comment: You can't deny this is horrible so far. Why CLOSE it? Why not shove it back to me and say "edit it to be more specific". Then I could edit it and shove it back to whoever closed it for approval.

Comment: @user, also, that will probably get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @user, also, ChrisF re-opend your question on WebApps.  It already has one answer.

Comment: No link to the new question like last time when it was "migrated".

Comment: Horrible, horrible, horrible. I like stackoverflow, but all this intra-site stuff is soooo annoying. I had to replace my bookmark 3 times just to have to most recent one. What happened to usability?

Comment: @user152305: You shouldn't take anything on the Stack Exchange sites personally. If it was closed/downvoted/moved/etc., then the most productive thing to do is to improve the question.

Comment: @user152305: Personally I like having multiple sites each with a specific focus. I don't want another Askville or Yahoo Answers.

Comment: That's great. I want a pile of gold coins, but if it's not practical and it doesn't work then stick with what does work.

Comment: *"Why not shove it back to me and say "edit it to be more specific"."* @user: Closing is actually an invitation to fix the question so that ti can be re-opened. Admittedly the UI doesn't say as much and people too rarely leave a comment to that effect, but there is a *re-open* mechanism and it *does* get used that way.

Comment: @user152305: Who exactly are you to be telling us what is or is not practical, and does or does not work?  I've downvoted your question *here* for your incredibly negative and belligerent attitude.  The world does not revolve around you and your questions.  Deal with it.

Comment: @Aarobot and who exactly are you to be telling me what I can and can't complain about? Belligerent? Why? Because I used the word "horrible"? Puhleaze. Get off your high horse. If you didn't like my post, then why are you here?

Comment: @user152305: I'm a non-anonymous user with a 2-year-long membership on the trilogy, over 1000 cumulative answers and an average of over 4 upvotes per answer. Are those credentials sufficient? You'll soon find that this is not your average discussion forum; we don't operate under an "If you don't like it, don't read it" policy here, our policy is "If it's garbage, then call it out and downvote it." I really didn't have a huge problem with your complaint (aside from the last sentence which was facepalm-worthy), but your follow-up comments make it pretty clear that you're not worth listening to.

Comment: @Aar, Nope, not good enough.  Go back to your cooking site! `:p` I had no issue with the initial complaint as well, but the comments leave me with a bad taste in my mouth.

Comment: Well, technically, I have more rep on MSO than I do on Cooking, so my statements here should have more weight than there; I just don't have any Jedi powers here.  Which is a good thing, because the volley of obnoxious comments would have turned me over to the Dark Side within seconds.

Answer (score 7):

> Just make one darned site, will you please?

No, we won't. There's multiple sites for a reason. I'm sorry to hear you had a bad experience, but you really should stick with it, you'll learn a lot more about why the community is set up the way it is as you dig into the sites a bit deeper.

Comment: Thanks, but no. I'd rather use a site where I just ask the question and not have to jump through a dozen hoops because it wasn't worded correctly _in your view_. At least give the moderators the ability to ask for clarification or more specifics before just CLOSING it.

Comment: I think you're looking for http://answers.yahoo.com/ then?

Comment: @user152305 `At least give the moderators the ability to ask for clarification or more specifics before just CLOSING it` WHY!? Even with the question closed you **can** edit it and flag for Mod attention when done.

Answer (score 1):

> **Web app site = application = software.**

Well, yes. But then again no.

Because the semantics are very different in several different ways:

- I can't use a webapp without access to the network. Sure the network is increasingly 
  ubiquitous, but it isn't actually *everywhere*, and even when its there there are placing that what let you use it *that way*.
- You generally don't control the version of the webapp you run. Because you load it from the web, and even if you take measures to lock the source the supplier isn't going to wory about protocol compatibility between versions because they *expect* you to track their changes.
- Webapp default to remote data while local executable default to local.
- Webapps run on a different set of platforms  [IE,mozilla,webkit,...]x[javascript,flash,...] than traditional software [windows,unix,...]x[x86,power,arm,JVM,...] in a way that renders the compatibility issues that plague the two classes very distinct.

Two categories of software with different issues, so two sites.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you could improve the question a little, especially by naming specific examples of software, or at least more specific categories (automated billing? automated payment processing? Customer Relationship Management (CRM)?) your underlying question might actually be just barely on topic for [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com/).

Wrestling with relationships with vendors of very expensive software with secret pricing and other silly games is exactly the kind of thing sysadmins deal with all the time.